# How do you call a variable in an array after sorting it in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

What I am trying to do is to a variable in an array after sorting (ascending order) it through a function.

The function I have is:

```
void xpPoints_Sorting ()
{
  int xpPoints[] = { 620, 500, 250, 1000, 830, 100, 370 };
  int temp;

  for(int i=1;i< 7;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<(7-i);++j)
            if(xpPoints[j] > xpPoints[j+1])
            {
                temp = xp[j];
                xpPoints[j] = xpPoints[j+1];
                xpPoints[j+1] = temp;
            }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I type xpPoints[0], in int main(), the output is still "620" and not "100".

```
  int main()
  {
  xpPoints_Sorting ();
  int xpPoints[] = { 620, 500, 250, 1000, 830, 100, 370 };
  cout <<  xpPoints[0];
  }
```

However, when I take I don't put it in a function and put it in int main(), it works perfectly fine and outputs "100".

How can I get it to work while keeping the function for sorting the array?

Comment: `xpPoints` is local to main isnt't it? where you passed array to function?

Comment: What gave you the idea that it's the same array in `main` and `xpPoints_Sorting`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In idomatic C++ what you're trying to do can be achieved like so using the `std::sort` algorthim:

```
  #include <algorithm>

  int main()
  {
     int xpPoints[] = { 620, 500, 250, 1000, 830, 100, 370 };
     std::sort(xpPoints,xpPoints + 7);
     cout << xpPoints[0];
  }
```

Comment: I am not sure if my teacher will allow me to use that but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about how scope works in C++.  You defined an array in `main()` called `xpPoints`, but it is *local* to that function.  Simply calling a function which sorts another array has no effect on your local `xpPoints` array.  Hence, when you print the first element nothing has changed.

To remedy this, you can refactor `xpPoints_Sorting()` such that it takes an array as input and then sorts it, e.g.:

```
void xpPoints_Sorting (int xpPoints[], int length)
{
    int temp;

    for (int i=1; i < length; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < (length-i); ++j)
            if (xpPoints[j] > xpPoints[j+1])
            {
                temp = xp[j];
                xpPoints[j] = xpPoints[j+1];
                xpPoints[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your `main()` function:

```
int main()
{
    int xpPoints[] = { 620, 500, 250, 1000, 830, 100, 370 };
    xpPoints_Sorting(xpPoints, 7);
    cout << xpPoints[0];
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing that but an error shows up and says "declaration of 'int xpPoints []' shadows a parameter"

Comment: @Confused.Student Remove the unnecessary declaration of the `xpPoints` array from your sorting function, q.v. my update code above.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much! I understand it now.

Comment: I think it's important to note, that it is (at least) useful to pass the length of the array to the function as well, instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: @slawekwin Good thinking.